# SSIS - How do you reference a variable with a custom name space from within a SSIS script task?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Custom name spaces can be created for variables within a SSIS package. However, I cannot reference them from within a script task when more than one variable within the collection has the same name but different name space.

Example:

```
Dts.Variables("YourVariableName").Value.ToString
```

However, this standard way of referencing a variable doesn't specify a name space.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you could just do

```
Dts.Variables("YourNameSpace::YourVariableName").Value.ToString
```

Does this not work for you?

Comment: This worked for me as well.  Documentation on how to access variables can be found here (has both C# and VB examples)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135941.aspx#Y506                   Also, I was able to access the variable without specifying the namespace.  Please make sure that your script task has the variable listed in either "ReadOnlyVariableS" or "ReadWriteVariables"